# Comparaison + pronom relatif + conditionnel

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, conditionnel

J'ai constaté récemment que l'auteur Luc Plamondon, parmi d'autres, emploie le conditionnel après avoir fait une comparaison telle que ces deux-ci :

> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle / à qui on **aurait** coupé les deux ailes.
>   
> <sub>— *Notre-Dame de Paris*, « Où est-elle ? » ([paroles](http://www.paroles-musique.com/paroles-Notre-dame_De_Paris-Ou_Est-elle-lyrics,p4498))</sub>
>
> Je me tiens debout / et je danse / comme un Andalou / qui **serait** jaloux.
>   
> <sub>— *La légende de Jimmy*, « Corrida » ([paroles](http://jimmy.legende.free.fr/cinema.htm#CORRIDA))</sub>

Il me parait sensé qu'on se servirait du conditionnel ici vu que les actes décrits sont hypothétiques. Toutefois, c'est bien inattendu pour moi en tant qu'anglophone. D'instinct j'aurais dit, à l'indicatif :

> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle / à qui on **a** coupé les deux ailes.
>   
> <sub>cp. She's like a swallow / whose two wings **have** been cut off.</sub>

Est-ce que le conditionnel est la seul combinaison temps/aspect qui peut servir ici ? Ou est-ce que l'indicatif y conviendrait, ou même le subjonctif ? Si on le peut varier, quel est l'élément dans ces phrases qui exigerait le conditionnel ? En somme, que faut-il savoir sur cet usage ?

Comment: "inattendu pour moi en tant qu'anglophone", ah bon ? "I can dance like an Andalusian who would be jealous. " (I agree "a jealous Andalusian" would be better but so would *un andalou jaloux.*  Not really the place to discuss this, I don't want to bring it to ELU, but we could discuss it in chat if you like.

Comment: L'anglais n'ayant pas vraiment de construction équivalente employé dans le language courant, ça ne me surprent pas qu'un anglophone trouve la construction inattendue. If faut utiliser une circonlocution du style "a sparrow that had had both its wings cut" ou "like an Andalusian, were he to be jealous", constructions lourdes et soit prétentieuses, soit désuètes, beaucoup plus rares en anglais que ne l'est l'emploi du conditionnel en français pour mettre l'accent sur l'aspect hypothétique de ce qu'on décrit.

Comment: @Philippe Ah, mais c'est en effect parce que l'anglais a bien une constuction équivalente employée dans le langage courant que j'ai été surpris ! Je dirais en anglais : "She's like a swallow whose wings **have been** cut off" et "I stay on my feet and dance like an Andalusian who **is** jealous." (Certes, "a jealous Andalusian" serait plus élégant, mais quand même.) L'objet de la comparaison, quoiqu'irréel, s'y décrit à l'indicatif.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak Il faudrait changer de forum pour discuter  des nuances de l'anglais, mais pour ne reprendre qu'un exemple, je pense que "whose wings have been cut off" équivaut à l’indicatif « à qui on a coupé les ailes » expliqué par Laure dans sa réponse. L'Andalou qui serait jaloux, c’était probablement pour avoir le bon compte de syllables dans la chanson !

Comment: @Philippe C'est ça... pour les syllabes et la rime en particulier. :) (Et je suis d'accord, je ne voulais traîner l'anglais dans la question que pour illuminer d'où vient ma confusion.)

Comment: @Philippe And ""whose wings had been cut off"  is the equivalent of  *à qui on aurait coupé les ailes*.

Comment: @Laure Pas tout à fait d'accord. La formule que vous proposez correspond à notre imparfait --  *à qui on avait coupé les ailes* comme fait accompli plutôt qu'à l'hypothéque *aurait coupé*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Les deux, conditionnel ou présent, sont possibles dans cette relative qui comporte le sens de « tel que ». L'emploi du conditionnel permet de se distancier d'une action non réalisée.

> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle à qui on a coupé les deux ailes.

→ le locuteur admet l'existence d'une telle hirondelle.

> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle à qui on aurait coupé les deux ailes.
>
> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle à qui on eût coupé les deux ailes.

→ une telle hirondelle est hypothétique, elle n'est que dans l'imagination du locuteur. L'emploi du conditionnel deuxième forme  plaçant peut-être l'action dans une état de réalisation encore plus improbable, en tout cas c'est plus littéraire.

Le futur serait aussi possible :

> Elle ressemble à une hirondelle à qui on aura coupé les deux ailes.

→ Avec le futur le locuteur met l'action dans la réalité mais une réalité non encore réalisée donc à classer entre le présent et le conditionnel pour ce qui est de la possibilité de réalisation de l'action.

---

Note : J'ai employé les termes de *conditionnel* et de *présent* dans le même sens que dans la question, à savoir en relation avec l'aspect, ici il s'agit de l'aspect accompli. L'aspect accompli en français est exprimé morphologiquement par un temps composé L'accompli dans le présent est exprimé dans la conjugaison par un passé composé (auxiliaire au présent), dans le futur par un futur composé (auxiliaire au futur), au conditionnel par un conditionnel passé (auxiliaire au conditionnel passé, première ou deuxième forme).

Comment: OK, donc c'est plus ou moins logique. C'est l'anglais qui parle des choses non-réalisées comme si elles l'étaient ...

Answer (score 2):

I'll just add that this particular type of standalone *conditionnel passé* without a usually accompanying « si » clause is not confined to a subordinate clause. I would say, for instance:

> J’***aurais gravi*** tous ces échelons pour qu'un charlatan quelconque me dise d'un coup sec : « il ne me reste qu'un an à vivre » ?!

The use of *passé composé* « j’***ai gravi*** » would make it a fact – which does not make sense in this context – whereas with *conditionnel passé* you can bring up a hypothetical, rhetorical question,  and express incredulity:

> ***Don't tell me*** all the sweat and blood I had put into to get where I am today was for nothing!?